# C++ Typedefs and operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, typedef

If you define a type like `typedef int MY_INT;` and go on to overload, say, the adition operator of MY_INT like

```
MY_INT operator+(MY_INT a, MY_INT b);
```

will

```
MY_INT a, b;
a + b;
```

be different from

```
int A, B;
A + B;
```

?

Sorry for any syntax errors. I'm not near a compiler and I want to ask this before I forget about it.

Comment: `MY_INT operator+(MY_INT a, MY_INT b);` This is not possible because you can only overload arithmetic operators when one of the parameters is of a class type.

Comment: I refer you to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135840/whats-the-best-way-to-force-the-user-of-a-c-function-to-acknowledge-the-semant

Comment: @Omnifarious, do you suggest wrapping `int` in a class so that I can overload its operators without affecting the system type?

Comment: you can't overload the operators for a system type.  So I suggest wrapping an int in a class so you can overload the operators at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. A typedef is actually an alias for another type. The original and typedef-ed types are the same.