# Define a new type and overload its operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible to create a type (let's say `degrees`) and define specific operators for it? Such as: `=, +, *, -, /, +=, *=, -=, /=`.

I'm wondering this because I need to use degrees for one of my programs and I don't want to use a `float` object because using `degrees a; a.value = 120; a.value = b.value + a.value;` is redundant over a simple `degrees a = 120; a = b+a;`.

Now why don't I just use:

```
typedef float degrees;
```

? Well, because I need one more thing. When I write

```
degrees a;
a = 120;
a += 300;
```

`a` should be equal to `60` (420-360) because I don't really need `a = 6150` when I can have `a = 30` with the same effect. So I'd overload those operators to keep the value between 0 and 360.

Is it possible? And, if so, how?

Comment: Absolutely.  Where do you get stuck?

Comment: *Is it possible to create a type (let's say degrees) and define for it specific operators?* Of course, through classes and operator overloading. Those are language features.

Comment: You can overload all those operators mentioned for your own data type.

Comment: @VaughnCato, I don't know what to use to create a new type. typedef [is not an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099695/c-typedefs-and-operator-overloading). Classes and struct neither. What else could be overloaded?

Comment: @VaughnCato: "I don't want to use an object because using degrees a; a.value = 120; a.value = b.value + a.value; is redundant over a simple degrees a = 120; a = b+a;."

Comment: Just because it is a class doesn't mean you have to do things like that.

Comment: @Als, if I use typedef I can't overload operators for them because typedef just create an alias of a standard type and base types can't be overloaded.

Comment: @VaughnCato, then please teach me. (In a specific answer)

Comment: Just having a class overloading the assignment, binary arithmetic, and compound assignment operators would give you the syntax you request.

Comment: You can code a degree class, with operator overloaded, this will allow to do things like a = 120 ; a = b+a ; You have to use class, otherwise you can choose other language not C++, like Pascal allows you define subrange. Like in Pascal, type degree = 420..360 ; var a:degree ;

Comment: @Jeffrey: Your Q says you will be ***creating an own type*** and my comment applies to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to your problem doesn't need Boost or any other libraries. You can achieve what you want by using C++ classes, and overloading both the mathematical operators you want (+, -, *, /, etc) and the assignment operators you want (=, +=, -=, etc) and the comparison operators you want (<, >, <=, >=, etc)... or really any operators you want!

For example:

```
#include <cmath>

class Degrees {
public:
    // *** constructor/other methods here ***
    Degrees& operator=(float rhs) {
        value = rhs;
        normalize();
        return *this;
    }
    Degrees& operator+=(const Degrees &rhs) {
        value += rhs.value;
        normalize();
        return *this;
    }
    Degrees operator+(const Degrees &rhs) {
        return Degrees(value + rhs.value);
    }

private:
    float value;
    void normalize() {
        value = std::fmod(value, 360);
    }
};
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
Degrees a, b; // suppose constructor initializes value = 0 in all of them
a = 10;
b = 20;
a += b; // now, a = 30.
Degrees c = a + b; // now, c = 50.
```

I've given you an example for overloading assignment and plus operators, but you can try this same thing with any other kind, and it should work.

Comment: fmodf is deprecated, you should use std::fmod .

Comment: This might be a noob question but isn't `this` a pointer? Why are you using `this.*`?

Comment: There is no need for the assignment operator here. The `Degree` argument should already be in accordance to the class's contract.

Comment: Seems to me some of these are a little more complex than necessary. For example, is there any reason that `operator+` couldn't be just `return Degrees(value + rhs.value);`?

Comment: Yes, @Jeffrey, `this` is a pointer. The use of `this.value` is  an error.

Comment: Yeah sorry, got rid of "this", unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a starting place:

```
class Degrees {
  public:
    explicit Degrees(float value) : value(normalized(value)) { }

    Degrees &operator+=(Degrees that)
    {
      value += that.value;
      return *this;
    }
  private:
    float value;
};

inline Degrees operator+(Degrees a,Degrees b)
{
  a += b;
  return a;
}
```

Example usage:

```
{
  Degrees a(120);
  Degrees b(300);
  Degrees c = a+b;
}
```

Comment: This is one case where I'd consider an implicit conversion constructor good.

Comment: (Style-wise, you should put mutating operators, like `+=`, as members, and then define non-mutating operators, like `+`, as free-functions that delegate to the member: `Degrees operator+(Degrees first, const Degrees& second) { first += second; return first; }`.)

Comment: @GManNickG: That's reasonable.  Changed.

Comment: The only thing that I don't understand is how do you get the `value` without using `a.value` (which is private in this case).

Comment: @aschepler, I disagree. If a function takes a unit, it's good to be explicit about what unit you pass in. User defined literals help this task. You can set them up to call it with whatever unit you want: `foo(120_deg); foo(3.14_rad);` You can still use them the old way as well: `foo(Degrees(120)); foo(Radians(3.14));`

Comment: @Jeffrey, The operator overload extracts the two values for you and adds them together. The semantics provided through that are exactly the same as adding the two values yourself.

Comment: @Jeffrey: You certainly could have a method to get the value, but you wouldn't need to use it often.

Comment: @VaughnCato, then shouldn't `value` be public in order to do `that.value` inside the operator overloading of `+=`?

Comment: @Jeffrey: No, member functions can access private members.

Comment: @Jeffrey, If you're confused because this object accesses the other object's `value`, it's on a class level, not an object level. They both belong to the same class, so they both have access to each other's private members.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this but accept the other one because it gave a more complete example and gave me an hint on how to normalize the values, but I really appreciate how fast you answered and the complete support you gave me through comments mostly.